# How to concatenate two lists element - wise and make a new list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists containing some quotes and their authors. How do I create a new list that contains both of the elements from the two lists?

```py
quotes = [
'Tough times don’t last. Tough people do.' ,
'Courage is one step ahead of fear.'
]

authors = [
'Robert H. Schuller',
'Coleman Young'
]
```

I want it to return

```py
quotes_list = [
'Tough times don’t last. Tough people do. - Robert H. Schuller' , 
'Courage is one step ahead of fear. - Coleman Young'
]
```

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[' - '.join(x) for x in zip(quotes, authors)]` `zip` lets you loop over elements of both lists at once, and `' - '.join()` combines the elements separated by a  dash

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for `str.join` and `zip` as many state:

Using `map` to make this speedy and `' - '.join` takes a sequence of strings and joins them to one separated by the initial string while `zip` makes an iterable of multiple sequences.

```
>>> quotes = ['Tough times don’t last. Tough people do.', 'Courage is one step ahead of fear.']
>>> authors = ['Robert H. Schuller','Coleman Young']
>>> list(map(' - '.join, zip(quotes, authors))))
['Tough times don’t last. Tough people do. - Robert H. Schuller', 'Courage is one step ahead of fear. - Coleman Young']
```

Alternatively you can use a list comprehension instead of map as well which is the more preferred way as it’s more readable and in most cases more optimized although I believe map should be faster here although I haven’t tested:

```
[' - '.join(*s) for s in zip(quotes, authors)]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is what you are looking for

```
zip(quotes, authors)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
res = [q + " - " + a for q, a in zip(quotes, authors)]
print(res)
```

*Output*

```
['Tough times don’t last. Tough people do. - Robert H. Schuller', 'Courage is one step ahead of fear. - Coleman Young']
```

Answer (score 0):

zip and join them:

```
list(map(" - ".join, zip(quotes, authors)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the exact behavior you're describing by using `zip()`, f-strings and a list comprehension:

```py
quotes_list = [f"{quote} - {author}" for quote, author in zip(quotes, author)]
```

Explanation:

The `zip()` function creates a list of tuples where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each list.

```py
zip(quotes, authors) = [('Tough times don’t last. Tough people do.', 'Robert H. Schuller'), ('Courage is one step ahead of fear.', 'Coleman Young')]
```

We then just iterate through the list and use f-strings to achieve the exact formatting.